# Sliding window over a string using python

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, data-science

I am working on a dataset as a part of my course practice and am stuck in a particular step. I have tried that using R, but I wish to do the same in python. I am comparatively new to python and so require help.

The data set consists of a column with name 'Seq' with seq(5000+) records. I have another column of name 'MainSeq' that contains the substring seq values in it. I need to check the presence of seq on MainSeq based on the start position given and then print 7 letters before and after each letter of the seq. i.e.
I have a a value in col 'MainSeq' as 'ABCDEFGHI**JKLMNO**PQRSTUVWXYZ'.
Col 'Seq' contains value JKLMNO
Start Position of J= 10 and O= 15

I need to create a new column such that it takes 7 letters before and after the start letter from J till O i.e. having a total length of 15

```
CDEFGHI**J**KLMNOPQ
DEFGHIJ**K**LMNOPQR
EFGHIJK**L**MNOPQRS
FGHIJKL**M**NOPQRST
GHIJKLM**N**OPQRSTU
HIJKLMN**O**PQRSTUV
```

I know to apply the logic on a specific seq. But since I have around 5000+ seq records, I need to figure out a way to apply the same on all the seq records.

```
seq = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
i = seq.index('J')
j = seq.index('O')
value = 7
for mid in range(i, 1+j):
    print(seq[mid-value:mid+value+1])
```

Comment: Where are 'J' and and 'O' coming from?

Comment: JKLMNO is a seq under the col 'seq' which belongs to the seq in the col 'MainSeq'. For all such values under the col 'seq' , I need to perform the above step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this will do exactly what you want, you've not really supplied a lot of data to test with, but it might work or at least give you a start.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'MainSeq':['ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWZYZ','ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWZYZ'], 'Seq':'JKLMNO'})

def get_sequences(seq, letters, value):
  
  sequences = [seq[seq.index(letter)-value:seq.index(letter)+value+1] for letter in letters]
  return sequences

df['new_seq'] = df.apply(lambda row : get_sequences(row['MainSeq'], row['Seq'], 7), axis = 1) 

df = df.explode('new_seq')

print(df)
```

Comment: Thankyou, Can I know how to apply this for a whole bunch values for the column? i.e. MainSeq contains around 5000+ records

Comment: The code should work for the entire column. In the code I posted I simply duplicated the data for the second row as I had nothing else to work with.